# Do the derivatives of the Bessel functions of the first kind with integer order have any singularities?

Tags: derivatives, bessel-functions

Do the derivatives of $J_\nu(z)$, the Bessel functions of the first kind with integer order $\nu$, have any singularities?

I am interested in the case where $z$ is real and $\nu$ is a positive integer.

The [definition](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.E2) is

$\mathop{J_{\nu}}\nolimits\!\left(z\right)=(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}\sum_{k=0}^{%
\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{(\tfrac{1}{4}z^{2})^{k}}{k!\mathop{\Gamma}\nolimits\!%
\left(\nu+k+1\right)}$

Since $\Gamma(x)$ is never zero I think that $J_\nu(z)$ has no singularities.

According to [derivative formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1)

$2\mathop{J_{\nu}}\nolimits'\!%
\left(z\right)=\mathop{J_{\nu-1}}\nolimits\!\left(z\right)-\mathop{J_{%
\nu+1}}\nolimits\!\left(z\right)$

I can compute the first derivative of $J_\nu$ by means of $J_{\nu-1}$ and $J_{\nu+1}$ and so since $J_{\nu-1}$ and $J_{\nu+1}$ have no singularities also the first derivative of $J_\nu$ will not have singularities.

The case with $\nu=0$ is handled by [this formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E3)

$\displaystyle\mathop{J_{0}}\nolimits'\!\left(z\right)=-\mathop{J_{1}}%
\nolimits\!\left(z\right)$

and so also the first derivative in case of order $\nu$ equal to zero is free of singularities.

For the second order derivative I think that I can apply two times the derivative formula and so I get again no singularities and the same happens with higher order derivatives.

Am I missing something?

What about [this different formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E2) for the derivatives? Does that $\frac{1}{z}$ give a singularity?

$\mathop{J_{\nu}}\nolimits'\!\left(z\right)=\mathop{J_{%
\nu-1}}\nolimits\!\left(z\right)-(\nu/z)\mathop{J_{\nu}}%
\nolimits\!\left(z\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bessel functions of the first kind with integer order are [entire functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function), i.e., are analytic in the entire complex plane. As such, they don't have any singularities, nor do their derivatives of any order. Any other expressions involving $J_\nu(z)$ and $1\over z$ (or whatever else, for that matter) can't change this fact.

You can verify that by checking the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Finding_the_radius_of_convergence) of the series in the definition. It is infinite.

BTW, $\Gamma(x)$ never being zero has nothing to do with $J_\nu(z)$ having or not having any singularities. Really, consider the series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty{z^k}$: the denominator is never zero (for there is no denominator at all), yet the function behaves suspiciously as $z$ approaches $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Bessel functions of positive order, evaluated at zero, are equal to zero:<sup>[1](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/03/01/01/)</sup>
$$ {J_\nu}(0) = 0 \, \Big|_{\nu>0} $$

The derivatives of the Bessel functions with integer order greater than one, evaluated at zero, are also equal to zero:
$$ {J_\nu}'(0) = 0 \, \Big|_{\nu>1} $$

Proof: Starting with the recurrence relation:
$$ {J_\nu}'(z) = \frac12 \left(J_{\nu-1}(z) - J_{\nu+1}(z) \right) \Big|_{\nu >1} $$
$$ {J_\nu}'(0) = \frac12 \left(J_{\nu-1}(0) - J_{\nu+1}(0) \right) \Big|_{\nu >1} $$
$$ {J_\nu}'(0) =  \frac12 \left(0 - 0 \right) = 0 \quad \blacksquare$$

Since the values of the derivatives at the origin, are zero, they are obviously not singularities.

The second term in the recurrence relation: 
$$ {J_\nu}'(z) = J_{ \nu-1}(z) - \nu \frac{{J_\nu}(z)}{z} $$

when $ z=0 $ and $ \nu>0 $; is not a singularity, but an *indeterminate form* of type $\! \tfrac00 $.
$$ {J_\nu}'(0) = J_{ \nu-1}(0) - \nu  \frac{0}{0} = 0  $$

The proper value of an indeterminate form can be determined by taking the limit $$ \lim\limits_{ z \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{J_\nu(z)}{z} \right) = 0 $$

We now know that the indeterminate form must evaluate to zero ($\nu \tfrac00 = 0$).
$$ {J_\nu}'(0) = J_{\nu-1}(0) - 0 = 0 $$

This is similar to the indeterminate form caused from lazily defining the sinc function as $\sin(x)/x$, instead of $\lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow z}(\sin(z)/z)$
$$ \operatorname{sinc}(0) = 1 = \lim\limits_{ x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right) \neq \frac{\sin(0)}{0}  $$

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no singularity will appear. However, the exact answer for your question lies in knowing the process of deriving the formula

$${{J'}_\nu }(z) = {J_{\nu  - 1}}(z) - {\nu  \over z}{J_\nu }(z)$$

I think the **firstly** derived formula is

$$z{{J'}_\nu }(z) = z{J_{\nu  - 1}}(z) - \nu {J_\nu }(z)$$

and then someone may divide it by $z$ to get what you mentioned so your mentioned formula is not valid for $z=0$.